# Modify CambridgeUS theme in beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm using `CambridgeUS` theme in my beamer presentation:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{beamer}                           % COMANDI INIZIALI
\usepackage[italian]{babel}                             % sillabazione italiana
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                             % Per le lettere accentate IN UNIX E IN WINDOWS
\usepackage{ragged2e}                                   % giustifica
\usepackage{amsmath}                                    % Per allineare le equazioni
\usepackage{amssymb}                                    % Per le lettere dell'indicatrice (mathbb)
\usepackage{graphicx}                                   % Per le figure

\renewcommand{\fontsubfuzz}{1.1pt}                          % Elimina i warning inutili

\justifying                                         % giustifica

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\date{29 Aprile 2015}
\author{Gabriele Mazza}
\title{Regressione con regolarizzazioni differenziali per dati spazio-temporali, con applicazione all'analisi della produzione di rifiuti urbani nella provincia di Venezia}

\begin{document}

%Frame del titolo
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How can I change it, having only two blocks at the bottom of the frame (with the same colors of the blocks on top), the first one with the author, the second with date (and number of frames)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CambridgeUS` theme uses `infolines` outer theme which design head and footlines. Footline template is defined with:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{infolines theme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

which declares three boxes for author, title and date and number. If you just want two, copy this definition and adapt it to your taste in your main file:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{beamer}                           % COMANDI INIZIALI
\usepackage[italian]{babel}                             % sillabazione italiana
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                             % Per le lettere accentate IN UNIX E IN WINDOWS
\usepackage{ragged2e}                                   % giustifica
\usepackage{amsmath}                                    % Per allineare le equazioni
\usepackage{amssymb}                                    % Per le lettere dell'indicatrice (mathbb)
\usepackage{graphicx}                                   % Per le figure

\renewcommand{\fontsubfuzz}{1.1pt}                          % Elimina i warning inutili

\justifying                                         % giustifica

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\date{29 Aprile 2015}
\author{Gabriele Mazza}
\title{Regressione con regolarizzazioni differenziali per dati spazio-temporali, con applicazione all'analisi della produzione di rifiuti urbani nella provincia di Venezia}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%Frame del titolo
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If background color for right boxes in head and footlines has to be changed, we need to look again in `infolines` theme which colors are used.

Right headline box uses `subsection in head/foot` while `date in head/foot` is used in footline. We just want to change background color for these boxes and replace it for `frametitle.bg` one. This can be done inserting

```
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{use=frametitle, bg=frametitle.bg}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{use=framtitle, bg=frametitle.bg}
```

in our preamble.

[image]

Comment: Where did you find the CambridgeUS theme definition?

Comment: @Youda008 you have to look for a file called `beamerthemeCambridgeUS.sty` in your system. This is a [link to this file in CTAN](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/theme/beamerthemeCambridgeUS.sty)